# Where should I put my defaults?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a web application that uses PHP for it's code,and MySQL for it's storage engine.  When working on my data model, I realized that I have a small issue with the handling of 'default' data.

I designed the MySQL schema to include the defaults, which made sense at the time because I was mostly manipulating the data 'by hand' -- it's a year later that we got around to adding a Control Panel to let others change the data.

The issue becomes how to handle 'default' values that are needed for some objects.  Technically, leaving things 'null' is also a default, but it wasn't one that particularly concerned me before now.

If I use the MySQL defaults, when I insert a new value I have to immediately turn around and query it to get the 'real' data out of the database.  If, on the other hand, I set my defaults up in PHP, I start violating DRY by having defaults in two places.  And if someone ever does a 'quick' fix and changes them in just one place, I could wind up with some pretty 'interesting' bugs to debug.  At the same time, I can't remove the defaults from MySQL, because the really are part of the data schema, and need to be left in it.

I'm willing to bet I'm either overlooking something, or making an invalid assumption somewhere, but I don't know what it is.  Anyone have any advice on how to handle this?

Edit:

For clarity, my PHP code might be something along the lines of:

```
$foo = new foo();
//Add in instance-specific data
$foo -> save;
```

Foo's save method would then run the query:

```
INSERT INTO FOO (bar1, bar2)
VALUES (:bar1, :bar2)
```

But that only inserts 2 of the (many) variables that Foo uses.  All this does is set me up in the 'default' state.  At the moment, I then have to run:

```
$foo= Foo::getFooWithId($foo->id); //I know I should use a DBA; this is legacy code
```

And $foo is then populated with the data that's been set up in the database.  E. G. bar3 and bar4 have defaults that aren't set when first creating the object -- users can change them later if they want to (and probably will), but they aren't part of the 'default' object.

Should I move those defaults into PHP?  Leave them in MySQL and pull out of it?  Violate DRY by putting them in both places?  Or am I missing a fourth, better option?

Comment: Throwing this out there re: questions this makes me thin about: But might you use a master value table to set defaults for fields in your schema, so that the application could always refer to it for both SELECT and INSERT/UPDATE ops? I'd be curious to know this as well. Foreign keys are an issue if it needs to be truly relational I suppose?

Comment: I'd populate the object with them in the default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You didn't show us an example query, but I'll assume what's wrong.</strike>

If you write your insert queries in PHP in such manner that you omit the elements that have default values, MySQL will take over and add them for you.

So, say you have a table with columns `id`, `user` and `comment`. Let's say that `comment` has a default value. What I'm saying is that you can make an insert query where you'd specify just  the `id` and `user` (or probably just `user`, if `id` is the primary, auto-incrementing index), and the `comment` will automatically receive the default value you set in your table definition.

EDIT

Whatever works best for your app design, really... See where will they be used the most and keep them there.

But a single rule I'd follow is: *don't have the defaults in more than one place, especially if they're overlapping (as opposed to extending)*.

Comment: I don't think that is what OP is asking. I think he is asking for best practices on where to locate the actual default values for cols if he doesn't want to rely on putting them in the schema for the purposes of his application.

Comment: @cerd You're probably right, I'll delete it if it doesn't help OP.

Comment: @RonLugge see my first comment, if that is what you are asking about (in short) you may want to edit for clarity - I was able to get the gist but your q requires reading a couple times.